# How to load data from array using driver class

Tags: java, arrays, class

Here is an assignment I am having trouble with.  I am still a newbie at Java.  I can't seem to load the Students name and their grades. The names and grades should be hardcoded into main, doesn't have to be 25.  So I did 4. I am having difficulty loading the data.
(Grades)  Create a blueprint named Student that has two fields, a String for their name and a one-dimensional array of integers which are their grades (different students may have different number of grades).  Finish the blueprint with a minimum of two constructors, a toString, and getters and setters.  You can add more methods as you see fit.
Write a driver program that has, at a minimum, the following structure:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // we do not know the number of students but there will not be >25
    Student[] students = new Student[25];

    int numStudents = loadStudents(students);
    printStudents(students,numStudents);

}

public static int loadStudents(Student[] s) {   }
public static void printStudents(Student[] s, int numStudents) {}
}
```

Here is what I have so far.

student class:

```
public class Student {

String name;
int[] grades;


public Student()
{
}

public Student(String n,int[] g)
{
    name=n;
    grades=g;
}

public String toString(){
return "";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int[] getGrades() {
    return grades;
}

public void setGrades(int[] grades) {
    this.grades = grades;
}


}
```

driverclass:

```
public class Driver {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // we do not know the number of students but there will not be >25
Student[] students = new Student[25];

    Student s1= new Student("John", new int[]{98, 92, 81});
    Student s2= new Student("Claire", new int[]{75, 84, 91, 39});
    Student s3= new Student("Steven", new int[]{88, 94, 65, 91,95});
    Student s4= new Student("Jason", new int[]{97, 89, 85, 82});





    int numStudents = loadStudents(students);
    printStudents(students,numStudents);

}

public static int loadStudents(Student[] s) {
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      s[i]=new Student();
      System.out.println(s[i]);
      }



    }

public static void printStudents(Student[] s, int numStudents) {
        if(numStudents < s.length){
            System.out.println(s[numStudents]);
            printStudents(s,numStudents-1);
        }   

      }
}
```

Comment: If we do this assignment for you, do we get the course credit too?

Comment: Lol no I just need to know how to load the data in I can do the rest.

Comment: Well, you might want to ask your teacher or TA what it means to "load" something.  You are printing the students in your "load" method.  Usually, printing is considered output, and loading is termed input.  You have to do the reverse of printing to "load".

Comment: I just put the print statement there to check if it was loading the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some elegant solution also available for your problem,however if you want to modify your existing code do as per below in Driver class,

public class Driver {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student[] students = new Student[25];

    Student s1 = new Student("John", new int[] { 98, 92, 81 });
    Student s2 = new Student("Claire", new int[] { 75, 84, 91, 39 });
    Student s3 = new Student("Steven", new int[] { 88, 94, 65, 91, 95 });
    Student s4 = new Student("Jason", new int[] { 97, 89, 85, 82 });

    List<Student> stuList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    stuList.add(s1);
    stuList.add(s2);
    stuList.add(s3);
    stuList.add(s4);

    int numStudents = loadStudents(students, stuList);
    printStudents(students, numStudents);

}

public static int loadStudents(Student[] s, List<Student> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        s[i] = list.get(i);
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
    return size;
}

public static void printStudents(Student[] s, int numStudents) {
    if (numStudents == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (numStudents < s.length) {
        System.out.println(s[numStudents]);
        printStudents(s, numStudents - 1);
    }
}
```

}

and modify the toString method in Student class.

```
public String toString(){
   String  str = "name : "+name;
   for(int i=0;i<grades.length;i++){
     str += grades[i] + " ";
   }
   return str;
}
```

I hope it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much I know I was missing something and that was the List and adding to the list. I kept just putting students.add(etc.); and forgot to actually initialize the list. duh!

Comment: I get one line of null printed first and it was missing a student so I put if(numStudents == -1) and that printed them right. But still prints a line saying null. Also how would I go about getting the average for each Student. I think I would have to create another method and pass each one in or could I just pass the whole List.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to return an int from your loadStudents function. Second, you have four Student variables declared in your main function which cannot be accessed right now in the loadStudents function. A quick solution would be to pass them as parameters and use a different constructor in the loadStudents function.

There are, of course, more elegant ways to do it, just consider this answer as a bit of help for your assignment :)